# Clojure Portal tool: Exception viewer and other custom viewers are missing

Tags: clojure, portal

I can start portal and inspect values as expected. But my portal tool doesn't include viewers such as Exception viewer or class viewer as different from the [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gByyg-m0XOg).

I checked the source code of the portal and the jar distribution file. The source code contains a namespace called `portal.ui.viewer`. This namespace is missing from the portal's jar distribution. Are those viewers included into some other jar file? How can I employ those viewers?

My deps.edn has the following alias

```
:inspect/portal-cli
{:extra-deps {djblue/portal {:mvn/version "0.15.1"}
                            cheshire/cheshire {:mvn/version "5.10.0"} ; json
                            clj-commons/clj-yaml {:mvn/version "0.7.0"} ; yaml
                            ,}}
```

I start portal using:

```
clojure -M:inspect/portal-cli
```

My user.clj includes:

```
(ns user
    (:require [portal.api :as p]))
(def portal (p/open))
(p/tap)
```

After repl starts, I run the following commands:

```
    (tap> {::exception (try (/ 1 0) (catch Exception e e))})
```

Here are the results:

[image: portal 01]

[image: portal 02]

[image: portal 03]

According to the demo video, I am supposed to see `portal.viewer/ex` as a viewer option. Then the stack trace would be listed in the proper format as here:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewer is available, but the exception needs to be data-fied first. Portal use to automatically datafy values but this behavior was problematic when I wanted access to the original object. You can datafy any selected value within the portal ui via the command palette (cmd + shift + p or ctrl + j).